# ANTLR4: How to print a tree in a convenient format

Tags: java, tree, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to print the generated tree in this format:

[image: picture]

So I need to have an ассеss to the information about the nodes of a tree. I generate it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    CharStream cs = new ANTLRFileStream("test.txt");
    ExampleLexer lexer = new ExampleLexer(cs);
    TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    ExampleParser parser = new ExampleParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.mainRule();
}
```

I can use `tree.getChild(int childNumber)` method to access the sub-trees and `tree.getChild(int childNumber).getText()` method to get their text, but I can't get any information about the nodes (I need to know the type of the token (if a node is a token) and the rule name (if that isn't a token)). How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the node is "encoded" as the node class... The ones actually representing a `Token` are a `TermninalRuleImpl`.

You can access the `Token` by the `getSymbol()`, so something like that should work:

```
if(node instanceof TerminalNodeImpl) {
    Token representedToken = ((TerminalNodeImpl) node).getSymbol();
}
```

If you need the token type you can check it by using the `getType()` method of the `Token` which will spit out a number that is defined as a constant in your parser-class.